# invok .NET webservice in Jboss using axis

Tags: .net, web-services, jboss, axis

I have a Java program  (.jar) that invok  a  .NET webservice and it works well. For another need, I need to call this webservice from a web application deployed in JBoss, I remade the same program already tested before but still I get this error message: RemoteException; nested exception is:
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not Allowed Within SOAP messages

Knowing that I do NTLM authentication.

Help me

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here, but if I understood correctly, when you use your .NET webservice invoking JAR *by itself*, it works fine, but when you use it *inside a service*  in JBoss, it does not work.

I surmise one of two things is going on here:

1. The program in the jar is quite clever and knows how to do NTLM authentication. When you run the program under *your* account, it works fine. When the JBoss service runs, perhaps it is being run by a user that is not recognized, cannot use NTLM authentication or may be on a platform that does not support it.
2. The program in the jar has all its own dependencies, but these conflict with the higher precedence libraries in JBoss so the call fails. In this case, you need to [isolate the JAR from the JBoss class loaders](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration).

To be of more specific help, edit your question and add this information:

- Version of JBoss, version of JBoss JVM, Platform JBoss is Running On
- Check the user under which each version of the app is running and present.
- A Stack Trace Of the Error when Running in JBoss